# Shape of an array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network

In Neural Networks and Deep Learning by DeepLearning.AI in Coursera I've a doubt in 2nd Week Programming Assignment

```
train_set_x_orig, train_set_y, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y, classes = load_dataset()
```

In above code segment they say that **train_set_x_orig is a numpy-array of shape (m_train, num_px, num_px, 3)**

Someone please help me to understand how shape of **train_set_x_orig** is **(m_train, num_px, num_px, 3)** and even i can't able to visualize the contents of numpy-array train_set_x_orig

Comment: This is something very specific to that code base. There is a function called `load_dataset()` that returns a tuple of objects, one of which is a numpy array called `train_set_x_orig`. What is the data about? Usually, images have three channels.

Comment: Example interpretation: `(m_train, num_px, num_px, 3)` = `n images` * `n pixels width` * `n pixels height = n pixels width` * `3 color-channels` (e.g. RGB)

Answer (score 1):

look like its an image.
in python use this code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in train_set_x_orig:
   img = np.array(i).astype('uint8')
   plt.imshow(img)
   plt.show()
```

this will show you all images 1 by one.
1st dimension is number of images,
2nd dimension is width
3rd dimension is height
4th dimension is color channel